# Getting application-defined error while referring to range

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to fill a formula using VBA. Here is the code

---

```
    Sub AssignRel()

    Dim strFormula As Variant
    Dim lastRow As Integer

    Sheets(1).Cells(1, 13).Value = "Assigned Release"
    strFormula = "someformula"

    lastRow = Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Sheets(1).Range("M2").Select
    Sheets(1).Range("M2").Formula = strFormula
    Range("M2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("M2:M" & lastRow)

    End Sub
```

---

When I run it, I get an Application-defined or object-defined error on this line:

```
   Sheets(1).Range("M2").Formula = strFormula
```

Comment: Actually this works fine for me. What does your "someformula" look like?

Comment: Unrelated, but `lastRow` should be `Long` so it doesn't overflow.

Comment: My formula is :        strFormula = "=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(I2,RelByEnv,2,FALSE)),""""Other"""",VLOOKUP(I2,RelByEnv,2,FALSE))"   This file will have less than 5000 rows so I should be ok with Integer

Comment: The problem is the formula.  Too many `"` see `"=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(I2,RelByEnv,2,FALSE)),""Other"",VLOOKUP(I2,RelByEnv,2,FALSE))"`

Comment: That did the trick! I did not expect that to be the issue. Thanks all !